# VBA Export sheet as a csv without losing focus of my current workbook

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I would like to export a sheet as a csv into a new dir but it doesn't work using the SaveAs method of the worksheet.

When I use SaveAs, I "lose focus" of my current workbook and the current workbook is now the csv file (in the new dir). I would like to export the sheet and keep the focus on the current workbook.

Comment: after saving your csv, can't you just "activate" the previous workbook?

Comment: How do I store the previous workbook ? I tried adding this :

dim myworkbook as workbook

set myworkbook = activeworkbook

wsSheet.saveas "dir\aa", xlCSV

myworkbook.activate


But this last line does nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you

```
Sub SaveCSV()
    Sheet1.Copy ' Change to whatever sheet you want to copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "MyFileCSV.csv", xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: The macro must be run from the workbook you are planning to keep. `Sheet1.Copy` will copy the sheet to a new workbook, and activate the destination workbook, save it, close it, and reactivate the workbook where your ran your macro (ThisWorkbook)

Comment: I have also edited the code so you are not prompted again to save the workbook before closing it